# What is the type of a Functional compound component with router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to use Function Compound Components with react-router.
What would be the type of Login.button in LoginComposition interface?

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'; 
import { Button } from '../../styles/login'; 
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

interface LoginComposition {    
    Button: <INSERT TYPE HERE>; 
}

const Login: FC & LoginComposition = ({ children }) => {    
    return <div>{children}</div>; 
};

const LoginButton: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children, history }) => {
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
};

Login.Button = withRouter(LoginButton);

export default Login;
```

Comment: You can use `function Login` instead of `const Login` and simply assign to `Login.Button` in which case TypeScript will automatically infer the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will answer the question directly, then I will explain a way to avoid the Typescript craziness. For something like this, you need to reorder the way you are defining the types and functions. You *could* extract the types the `react-router` package and reverse-engineer the type `withRouter()` generates but I checked the package and its not pretty, nor would it be sustainable should the type change. What you need is to wrap `LoginButton` in `withRouter(...)` immediately, or create a second variable to store it. Examples here:

```js
const LoginButton = withRouter(({ children, history }) => {
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
});

// OR

const LoginButton: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children, history }) => {
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
};

const WrappedLoginButton = withRouter(LoginButton);
```

Then, the final step would be to put the `Login` component and interface below the `LoginButton` (or `WrappedLoginButton`) and utilize `typeof` to get extract the typing from it. The whole setup would look like this (using `WrappedLoginButton`)

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'; 
import { Button } from '../../styles/login'; 
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginButton: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children, history }) => {
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
};

const WrappedLoginButton = withRouter(LoginButton);

interface LoginComposition {    
    Button: typeof WrappedLoginButton; 
}

const Login: FC & LoginComposition = ({ children }) => {    
    return <div>{children}</div>; 
};

Login.Button = WrappedLoginButton;

export default Login;
```

To assist making the code easier, is there a reason you can't just use the `useHistory()` hook? Especially with Typescript, higher order components can be quite finicky. If you utilize the hook like so:

```js
const LoginButton: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
};
```

That will alleviate the need for the withRouter syntax, meaning that the types can be boiled down to this:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'; 
import { Button } from '../../styles/login'; 
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginButton: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push('foo')}>{children}</Button>; 
};

interface LoginComposition {    
    Button: typeof LoginButton; 
}

const Login: FC & LoginComposition = ({ children }) => {    
    return <div>{children}</div>; 
};


Login.Button = withRouter(LoginButton);

export default Login;
```